# Applying a function to get comma separated string using multiple columns in DataFrame and create a third column

Tags: r

I am trying to sort names in a row and create a comma separated string which would create another column.

This being my sample data.frame .

```
df=data.frame(A=c("A","K","B","D","F"),B =c("E","C","D","A","K"))

  A B
1 A E
2 K C
3 B D
4 D A
5 F K
```

The Output I am trying to get would be like this

```
  A B C
1 A E A , E
2 K C C , K
3 B D B , D
4 D A A , D
5 F K F , K
```

So far I have tried this :

```
lapply(df,FUN=paste(sort(df$A,df$B),collapse=" , "))
mapply(FUN= function(x,y)paste(sort(x,y),collapse=" , "),df$A,df$B)
```

Here I am trying to sort column values and paste them using `','` to create a unique pair name.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `mapply`, but since your data are factors, you need to coerce to character to they sort properly:

```
df$C <- mapply(function(x, y){paste(sort(c(as.character(x), as.character(y))), 
                                    collapse = ',')}, df$A, df$B)
df
#   A B   C
# 1 A E A,E
# 2 K C C,K
# 3 B D B,D
# 4 D A A,D
# 5 F K F,K
```

---

To simplify a bit, you can just use `apply` to iterate over the rows:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x){paste(sort(x), collapse = ',')})
```

Since it treats `df` as a matrix, it converts everything to character, which happens to be what you want for the sample data.

Also see `tidyr::unite` for pasting two columns together, though it can't easily sort.

Answer (score 6):

If you only have 2 columns, you can use `pmax` and `pmin` to avoid any costly looping code. E.g.:

```
with(lapply(df, as.character), paste(pmin(A,B),pmax(A,B),sep=",") )
#[1] "A,E" "C,K" "B,D" "A,D" "F,K"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
> for( i in 1:nrow(df)){
+     df$C[i]<-paste0(as.character(unlist(sort(df[i,1:2]))),collapse=" , ")
+ }
> df
> df
  A B     C
1 A E A , E
2 K C C , K
3 B D B , D
4 D A A , D
5 F K F , K
```

Comment: I believe @alistaire 's answer does that